# How to move a Label without stopping?

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have a label which moves from the right to the left under a TabControl. I switch into the tabs every 10 seconds with a timer. The problem is, that the label stops moving while the tab is changing. And this is really annoying. How to fix that?
This is the code, where i move the label:

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    LabelNews.Left = LabelNews.Left - 5
    If LabelNews.Left <= 0 Then
        LabelNews.Left = 1867
    End If
    Timer2.Stop()
    Timer2.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: is your Timer a global variable? Try to re-start it in one of TabControl's refresh events.

Comment: The human eye is *very* sensitive to a change in motion.  A survival of the fittest trait that stopped your great, great, .., great grand father from being eaten by a lion.   You can have smooth motion from a timer or you can have a tabpage stuffed with controls that take a long time to paint.  You can't have both.